# ScrollTo not scrolling to the top

Tags: javascript, lit

I am trying to update the div position after a click, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried debugging it, when I use the keyword debugger, it actually works but it doesn't work without it. Following is my code

```
  scrollToTop(){
    console.log(this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".results"))
    return this.shadowRoot.querySelector("results").scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
```

```
switch(args){
      case "desc":
        this.active = [...this.active.reverse()];
        this.scrollToTop();
        //debugger 
        //putting in debugger and pausing the code does make it work but not without it
        break;
}
```

I have trimmed down the code to bare minimum

I have tried seeing if the element exist, yes it does. I have tried debugging it (putting in debugger) works fine but it is not a solution.

Edit: [Here](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-RnJ1aXRzPC9hPlxuICAgICAgICAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0nc29ydCcgP2hpZGRlbj0nJHt0aGlzLmlzSGlkZGVufSc-IFxuICAgICAgICA8dWwgY2xhc3M9J3Jlc3VsdHMnPlxuICAgICAgICAgPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9XCIjXCI-QXBwbGU8L2E-PC9saT5cbiAgICAgICAgIDxsaT48YSBocmVmPVwiI1wiPkJhbmFuYTwvYT48L2xpPlxuICAgICAgICAgPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9XCIjXCI-Q2hlcnJ5PC9hPjwvbGk-XG4gICAgICAgICA8bGk-PGEgaHJlZj1cIiNcIj5EYXRlczwvYT48L2xpPlxuICAgICAgICAgPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9XCIjXCI-RWdncGxhbnQ8L2E-PC9saT5cbiAgICAgICAgIDxsaT48YSBocmVmPVwiI1wiPkd1YXZhLzxhPjwvbGk-XG4gICAgICAgICA8bGk-PGEgaHJlZj1cIiNcIj5Ib25leWRldy88YT48L2xpPlxuICAgICAgICAgPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9XCIjXCI-SW5kaWFuIFBydW5lPC9hPjwvbGk-XG4gICAgICAgICA8bGk-PGEgaHJlZj1cIiNcIj5KYWNrZnJ1aXQ8L2E-PC9saT5cbiAgICAgICAgIDxsaT48YSBocmVmPVwiI1wiPktpd2k8L2E-PC9saT5cbiAgICAgICAgIDxsaT48YSBocmVmPVwiI1wiPkxpbWU8L2E-PC9saT5cbiAgICAgICAgIDxsaT48YSBocmVmPVwiI1wiPk1hbmdvPC9hPjwvbGk-XG4gICAgICAgICA8bGk-PGEgaHJlZj1cIiNcIj5OZWN0YXJpbmU8L2E-PC9saT5cbiAgICAgICAgIDxsaT48YSBocmVmPVwiI1wiIEBjbGljaz0keygpPT57XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgdGhpcy5zY3JvbGxUb1RvcCgpO1xuICAgICAgICAgIH19Pk9saXZlPC9hPjwvbGk-XG4gICAgICAgIDwvdWw-XG4gICAgICAgIDwvZGl2PlxuICAgICAgICBgO1xuICB9XG59XG5jdXN0b21FbGVtZW50cy5kZWZpbmUoJ3NpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZycsIFNpbXBsZUdyZWV0aW5nKTtcbiJ9LHsibmFtZSI6ImluZGV4Lmh0bWwiLCJjb250ZW50IjoiPCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw-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) is a working example (bare minimum), when I click on last item in the list e.g. Olive. It should scroll to the top. The problem on this is

1. I cannot stimulate toggle on Click
2. The error in the console when I click olive, it says `peError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollTo')`

But like I exaplined above in my local code, there is no error yet it doesn't work.

Comment: Giving that it works with `debugger` it suggests that the problem is in focus. Like if you put `debugger` then button that you clicked loses focus and hence allows browser to scroll. Sometimes browser won't scroll cause other element is in the users focus so it doesn't allow scrolling. Try programmatically un-focus button using `blur` or focus on some other element, like a body or a div
Without actual structure of the page it is difficult to provide exact solution, please consider creating sandbox

Comment: @NikitaChayka thanks but it is not a button but a click on anchor. I will try to create a sandbox and update.

Comment: Anchor - the same thing, browser keeps focus on anchor then and doesn't allow scroll if anchor will be hidden by the result of the scrolling

Comment: @NikitaChayka I have updated the code with bare minimum working code.

Comment: What are you logging to console there? `querySelector(".results")` And what are you actually using, to try and call the `scrollTo` method on? `querySelector("results")`. You got no element with the _tag name_ `results` anywhere.

Comment: And `.results` is not your actually scrollable element there to begin with - `.sort` is; that one you actually applied `overflow: scroll` on. You want `return this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".sort").scrollTo(0, 0);`

Comment: @NikitaChayka `.results` is the name of `ul` when I clicked on last item e.g. Olive, it does `console.log` the `ul`. I m giving the name `.results` so that when scroll happens it goes to the top of the `ul`

Answer (score 1):

Use `.scrollIntoView` instead. See [Sandbox](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-e1xuICAgICAgICAgICB0aGlzLnRvZ2dsZSgpXG4gICAgICAgICB9fT5GcnVpdHM8L2E-XG4gICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSdzb3J0JyA_aGlkZGVuPScke3RoaXMuaXNIaWRkZW59Jz4gXG4gICAgICAgIDx1bCBjbGFzcz0ncmVzdWx0cyc-XG4gICAgICAgICA8bGk-PGEgaHJlZj1cIiNcIj5BcHBsZTwvYT48L2xpPlxuICAgICAgICAgPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9XCIjXCI-QmFuYW5hPC9hPjwvbGk-XG4gICAgICAgICA8bGk-PGEgaHJlZj1cIiNcIj5DaGVycnk8L2E-PC9saT5cbiAgICAgICAgIDxsaT48YSBocmVmPVwiI1wiPkRhdGVzPC9hPjwvbGk-XG4gICAgICAgICA8bGk-PGEgaHJlZj1cIiNcIj5FZ2dwbGFudDwvYT48L2xpPlxuICAgICAgICAgPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9XCIjXCI-R3VhdmEvPGE-PC9saT5cbiAgICAgICAgIDxsaT48YSBocmVmPVwiI1wiPkhvbmV5ZGV3LzxhPjwvbGk-XG4gICAgICAgICA8bGk-PGEgaHJlZj1cIiNcIj5JbmRpYW4gUHJ1bmU8L2E-PC9saT5cbiAgICAgICAgIDxsaT48YSBocmVmPVwiI1wiPkphY2tmcnVpdDwvYT48L2xpPlxuICAgICAgICAgPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9XCIjXCI-S2l3aTwvYT48L2xpPlxuICAgICAgICAgPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9XCIjXCI-TGltZTwvYT48L2xpPlxuICAgICAgICAgPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9XCIjXCI-TWFuZ288L2E-PC9saT5cbiAgICAgICAgIDxsaT48YSBocmVmPVwiI1wiPk5lY3RhcmluZTwvYT48L2xpPlxuICAgICAgICAgPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9XCIjXCIgQGNsaWNrPSR7KCk9PntcbiAgICAgICAgICAgICB0aGlzLnNjcm9sbFRvVG9wKCk7XG4gICAgICAgICAgfX0-T2xpdmU8L2E-PC9saT5cbiAgICAgICAgPC91bD5cbiAgICAgICAgPC9kaXY-XG4gICAgICAgIGA7XG4gIH1cbn1cbmN1c3RvbUVsZW1lbnRzLmRlZmluZSgnc2ltcGxlLWdyZWV0aW5nJywgU2ltcGxlR3JlZXRpbmcpO1xuIn0seyJuYW1lIjoiaW5kZXguaHRtbCIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiI8IURPQ1RZUEUgaHRtbD5cbjxoZWFkPlxuICA8c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9XCJtb2R1bGVcIiBzcmM9XCIuL3NpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZy5qc1wiPjwvc2NyaXB0PlxuPC9oZWFkPlxuPGJvZHk-XG4gIDxzaW1wbGUtZ3JlZXRpbmcgbmFtZT1cIldvcmxkXCI-PC9zaW1wbGUtZ3JlZXRpbmc-XG48L2JvZHk-XG4ifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJwYWNrYWdlLmpzb24iLCJjb250ZW50Ijoie1xuICBcImRlcGVuZGVuY2llc1wiOiB7XG4gICAgXCJsaXRcIjogXCJeMi4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcIkBsaXQvcmVhY3RpdmUtZWxlbWVudFwiOiBcIl4xLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwibGl0LWVsZW1lbnRcIjogXCJeMy4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcImxpdC1odG1sXCI6IFwiXjIuMC4wXCJcbiAgfVxufSIsImhpZGRlbiI6dHJ1ZX1d)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: While you example works fine, for some reason. My code won't work, there is no error in console. I tried doing `this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".-results>li").innerHTML = 'hello world';` that work but for some odd reason, it won't scroll to first. Is there any other way to debug ot achieve same?

Comment: Didn't get you mean

Comment: The issue on my local code still is the same as in question even after doing the amends you suggested.